Cannot create custom templates for file screening in Windows server
I'm using Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. I have installed the FSRM (File Server Resource Manager) feature in it. When I tried to create a new file screen template, the following error was thrown, which says An unexpected error has occured. Please check application event log for more details
enter image description here
I couldn't find related log entries in the application logs. I suspect this might be due to  a corrupted installation of FSRM. But I couldn't verify it.
I do have another question here. I tried to create a custom template as I wanted to implement whitelisting of file types. In FSRM I'm only able to find filegroups that can be blocked. I would be grateful if anyone can show me a way to implement whitelisting using FSRM.
Ex: Allow only .docx file and deny all other file types.
